# Side menu isn't showing up when clicked on menu image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wrote a code where side menu will be displayed after clicking the menu image. Its code is as given [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/6uepm0rq/) I'm using jQuery for this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#logoDiv, #pageTitle').click(function () {
        if (!$("#searchMenu").is(':visible')) {
            $('#searchMenu').show('slide', 'left', 300);
        } else {
            $('#searchMenu').hide('slide', 'left', 300);
        }
    });
}
```

But `searchMenu` which is a side menu isn't showing up when clicked on menu image. How can I fix it?

Comment: I've added a fiddle already, check question properly. Here is jsfiddle link if you missed it: http://jsfiddle.net/6uepm0rq/

Comment: My mistake then !! here also means, here below ! so i missed ! apologies !

Comment: If you open your developer console it should say something along the lines: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list     file.js:9`

Comment: @Ajay I updated My answer

Comment: @Sathish: check my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you missing `)` in end of ready function
>
> You need to insert jquery ui for easing effects

Just try this.,!

```js
$('#logoDiv, #pageTitle').click(function () {
  if (!$("#searchMenu").is(':visible')) {
    $('#searchMenu').show('slide', 'left', 300);
  } else {
    $('#searchMenu').hide('slide', 'left', 300);
  }
});
```

```css
#logoDiv {
    width: 52px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 1.5%;
    padding-left: 4%;
    color: white;
    background-color: #FFA500;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
#pageLogo {
    display: block;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    height: 67%;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 14%;
}
#pageTitle {
    background-color: #FFA500;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 1%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-right: 22%;
}
#inheader {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
}
.mainDiv {
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1%;
}
#user {
    /*display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;*/
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}
#searchMenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 9%;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
    height: 80%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    min-width: 250px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
#searchMenu >.list-group >.list-group-item {
    float: none;
    min-width: 150px;
    background-color: #201423;
    ;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>   
    <div id="headDiv" role="banner">
        <div id="logoDiv"> <span id="pageLogo"><img src="images/index_menu_active_phone.png" id="logo"></span>

        </div>
        <div id="pageTitle" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="center-block">
                <img src="images/cart.png" class="img-rounded" alt="I" width="30" height="30" /> <span style="font-family: 'customfont';" id="inheader">Instore</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container mainDiv">
        <div id="searchMenu" class="col-xs-4">Helloiudhfskjdzgfsiukydhfsiuejhgfsiudjh</div>
    </div>
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Well... it is working in that jsfiddle, but not in my code

Answer (score 2):

The end of your jQuery function is wrong.

[See Working Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uepm0rq/1/)

Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#logoDiv, #pageTitle').click(function () {
        if (!$("#searchMenu").is(':visible')) {
            $('#searchMenu').show('slide', 'left', 300);
        } else {
            $('#searchMenu').hide('slide', 'left', 300);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Funny... It is working in that jsfiddle, but not in my code

Comment: Make sure the jsfiddle and your code is exactly the same. and you include jQuery

Comment: My code is a bit different. `searchMenu` is an id that has been associated with an external html page called `menu.html` which is supposed to slide from left when clicked on menu image.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right. Just include jQuery UI library. To show the sliding and other effects you need jQuery UI Library.
//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js

here is working Fiddle with your code.(You have missed bracket in your fiddle)

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prasadFiddle/6uepm0rq/7/)

This plugin extends jQuery's built-in .show() method. If `jQuery UI` library is not loaded, calling the .show() method may not fail directly, as the method still exists. However, the expected behavior will not occur. Same is the case for .hide() method.